# Finding substrings in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, substring, c-strings

I am having trouble with this problem any tips on how to solve it would be appreciated.

> This function finds the first occurrence of toFind in original and returns an integer representing the index of the first element of the toFind substring in original.  For example if toFind was 'man' and original was 'superman' the function would return 6 since the begining of 'man' in 'spiderman' is position 7.  If the function does not find a substring it should return -1.

What I have so far:

```
{
   printf("%s\n%s\n", original, toFind);
   int j, i, k, start, length;
   i = 0;
   j = 0;
   k = 0;
   length = (int)strlen(original);
   start = 0;

   printf("%d\n", length);

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(toFind); ++i)
   {
      while (j != (length - 1))
      {
         printf("j: %d\n", j);
         if (toFind[i] == original[j])
         {            

            while (k != strlen(toFind))
            { 
               if (toFind[i + k] == original[j + k])
               {
                  printf("k: %d\n", k);

                  k = k + 1;
                  start = j;
               }  
               else
               {
                  k = 0;

               } 
            }
         }
         else
         {
            ++j;

         }        
      }
  }
   printf("%d\n", start);
    if (k == strlen(toFind))
      {
         printf("Word found\n");
         return start;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Word not found\n");
         return -1;
      }

return 0;
```

Comment: You need to describe a *specific* problem. What is wrong with what you have? How is it not working as you want?

Comment: use `strstr`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase value of j by 1 whether condition is true or false. In your code, when if condition is true, value of j is not increasing after that. So it stuck there and always get true value at that condition. I might not clarify that to you.  Just replace  `else{ ++j; }` with  `++j;`.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to do your work for you, but here's a short example I came up with. It's untested. Basically it iterates over string 1 until it finds a matching character then iterates over both strings until it finds a character that doesn't match or it runs out of characters.

```
const char* str1 = "Hello find me" , *str2 = "find";
int i = 0;
while (str1[i]) {
    while (str1[i] && str1[i] != str2[0]) {
        ++i;
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (str1[i + j] && str1[i + j] == str2[j]) {
        ++j;
    }
    if (!str2[j]) {return i;}
}
return -1;
```